# How to reconfigure phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
Error: "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php"  

Cannot connect: invalid settings.   
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I was using LAMPP with mysql password as root. Then I installed xampp on Ubuntu 15.04. After that I'm unable to access my phpmyadmin page.

I tried changing config file removing cookies but still the same error.

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

run the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

You need to reconfigure it because lamp and xampp run phpmyadmin in different ports. So, it is probably a port conflict. You can also open server.xml in your lampp and change the port no. which would be different from that of xampp. Then both MySQL (of xampp and lamp as well) will run.

Comment: thnx...   I tried http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin   it worked!!

Comment: thanks! turns out when the gui screen comes asking between apache and lightppd, we're supposed to press space to select apache - even though its highlighted, it's not selected. This commands brings up that screen again so we can configure properly in case we missed it out the last time. one proper tutorial warning about this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: It's so easy to miss that lame ncurses spacebar-to-check-apache step!  I did the same thing, and this also fixed it for me, thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Just run the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
```

[image]

Comment: Weird, just use it. I have the prompt for the Apache settings but not this screen to reinstall the database.